# VueJS: read div content from its id

Tags: vuejs2

In my first example, I have in my component's template:

```
<div id="hello">hello world</div>
```

When `console.log(this.$refs['hello'])` is called in `myMethod()`, I get `undefined` in the console.

In my second example, I have:

```
<div v-for="item in data">
  <div :id="'hello-'+item.id">hello {{ item.id }}</div>
</div>
```

When `console.log(this.$refs['hello-1'])` is called in `myMethod()`, I also get `undefined` in the console.

What's wrong in my code ?

Comment: `$refs` are populated by the [`ref` attribute](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref), not `id` attribute

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get element with `refs` by giving that element `id`. You should bind `ref` to that element. Here is an example:

```
<div v-for="item in data" :key="item.id">
  <div :id="'hello-'+item.id" :ref="'hello-'+item.id">hello {{ item.id }}</div>
</div>
```

And also don't forget to bind **key** to your iterating elements with `v-for`